# Best way to implement emoticons in a chat using Angular o Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, emoticons

I am looking for a way to add the funcionability of emoticons in a chat page.

Answer (score -2):

This is a pretty broad question.  I will hope to answer what I believe you are asking.  The basic architecture for something like this would be your basic chat client, and a modal based selector of images.  Once the image is selected, it would be appended to the list, div, or whatever element you are placing new messages in.  If you have any more detailed questions I will be watching this thread.